# Unable to add outlook account after updating to ios10

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, ms-office

After updating my iPhone to IOS 10 yesterday, I am unable to add an outlook account.

So here's what I'm doing:

- I go to settings->mail->accounts, then tap "add account", and select "outlook".
- A pop-up appears which loads Microsoft’s login page. I enter my username and password there, and click "login".
- The page then asks me for a code from the two-step verification app. I enter that code and press "confirm" (or whatever the button is called).
- After that another page appears which says that I am about to grand the following permissions (access to mail, contacts, etc.) to IOS, and asks me to confirm that.
- I press "Yes", and then this window simply dissapears, leaving me back at the screen with mail provider selection (the one with "outlook", "exchange", "google", etc on it).

The outlook account is never added to my phone. However if I login to my outlook account from my PC and go to security settings->permissions, I can see that the permission for "IOS" *has* been created properly, it's just that the account is never added to my phone for some reason. Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use Exchange instead of Outlook as mail provider. It offers exactly the same functions, including push notifications. Create a new app password in your Outlook account security settings for login.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a gmail adress. It was not able to add the account because it was not safari set as the browser used to open link from outlook app